# Can we run a JavaFX sesktop application in the web?

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application

I am developing a JavaFX application. As my development is almost complete, I would like to know if we can run our JavaFX app in a web browser. I have already read [many posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229508/convert-javafx-desktop-app-to-web-app) that state that we can't run it now.

It is very confusing to determine whether we can run desktop application in the browser or not, as all posts I have read are old.

Comment: There is somewhere a software package that provides I think JSF components for that. It is however a huge difference in control flow and with a parallel visual design. You might expect many things not working properly, needing changes. But you might create a Windows Setup especially with modular java > 9. I did Inno-Setup with JDK13 on a JavaFX application.

Comment: https://www.jpro.one/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What has been said so far is simply not true. You can run JavaFX application in a browser even without any plugin or such. Just have a look here: https://www.jpro.one/

Just look at their demo page https://www.jpro.one/?page=demos to see many well known JavaFX examples. You can try them out yourself there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also compile it to javascript a la GWT using **webfx-project** (https://github.com/webfx-project/webfx).

The result is a single-page webapp (only HTML + javascript) running in the browser. And by the looks of the demos the result is exactly as the original JavaFX application.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop using swing, then i recommend trying https://www.webswing.org